# iRegex for date in user entered textfield

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, validation

I have an input box and the user can write his DOB(mm/dd/yyyy) into the box.
Before I save the data I like to test for valid input. I am using Regexlite.h and Regexlite.m.I have the regular expression too. I want to compare the regex to the user entered value in text box.But am not knowing how to do it.

Any idea how to test for a valid date?  (in .NET I use a simple regex but for the iPhone sdk I am a bit helpless) - but somebody must have been done this before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex you can use to parse it if your looking for something else just leave me a comment

`^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do more validation than that---you don't want anything happening on 30 February nor allow a birth-year of 1001 and 3001 (time-travellers and Methusaleh's Children can go hang).

Perhaps someone cleverer than I could do this all with regular expressions, but I'd suggest just looking at the string and using some logic.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using `UIDatePicker` to prevent user to enter your own not valid date.